# SELECT SQL Statement not working as expected in VB.net Console application

Tags: sql, vb.net, console-application

I know there are similar posts regarding this but i cant seem to find anything that works.

I'm still new to VB and this which is probably obvious is driving me mad.

What im looking to do is to Run a SQL SELECT and email the results to those who require it.

When i run it I'm getting the 'ELSE' email which states that there is nothing on HOLD, however running the Query in SQL Server Management Studio does present results.

Here is what i have:

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim connection As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.connectionString)
    connection.Open()
    Dim sqlCommand As SqlCommand
    log(" Processing - Searching SQL Database for Held ONLN Jobs ")

 Dim sqlQ1 As String = "Select [JobID] FROM [cemail].[dbo].[JobTb] " +
               "WHERE ApplicationID = 7 AND Status = 10 ORDER BY [JobID]"

    sqlCommand1 = New SqlCommand(sqlQ1, connection)
    Dim result = sqlCommand1.ExecuteScalar()

   Dim sqlQ2 As String = "Select [JobID],[JobNumber],[ApplicationID],[GeneratedDate]," +
                "[ReceivedDate],[CompletedDate],[Status],[ExpectedRecordNumber]," +
                "[ReceivedRecordNumber],[BadRecordNumber] " +
                "FROM [cemail].[dbo].[JobTb] " +
                "WHERE ApplicationID = 7 AND Status = 10"
    sqlCommand2 = New SqlCommand(sqlQ2, connection)
    Dim reader As SqlDataReader = sqlCommand2.ExecuteReader()
    While reader.Read()
        Dim jobID = reader(0)
        Dim jobNumber = reader(1)
        Dim appID = reader(2)
    End While

    If (result > 0) Then

 SendEmail(My.Settings.emailuser1, "Current Held Jobs", "Hello," & jobID & "Kind Ragards" )
    Else

        SendEmail(My.Settings.emailuser1, "No Jobs on Hold", "There are no Jobs Currently on Hold" )


    End If


    connection.Close()

    log("Finished")
End Sub
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not call on [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) when you pass a Select statement.
As from the remarks on MSDN

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. ......... For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1.......

You could change the statement to simplify your query in this way

```
Dim sqlQ As String = "Select count(*) as recFound FROM [cemail].[dbo].[JobTb] " + 
                     "WHERE ApplicationID = 7 AND Status = 10"

sqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlQ, connection)
Dim result = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar()
```

Also, in the code above there is no need to use a transaction.

**EDIT** Seeing your comment I will show also the part for reading back the values from the database using an [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

```
Dim sqlQ As String = "Select [JobID],[JobNumber],[ApplicationID],[GeneratedDate]," +
                    "[ReceivedDate],[CompletedDate],[Status],[ExpectedRecordNumber]," + 
                    "[ReceivedRecordNumber],[BadRecordNumber] " + 
                    "FROM [cemail].[dbo].[JobTb] " + 
                    "WHERE ApplicationID = 7 AND Status = 10"

sqlCommand = New SqlCommand(sqlQ, connection)
Dim reader As SqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
While reader.Read()
     Dim jobID = reader(0)
     Dim jobNumber = reader(1)
     Dim appID = reader(2)
     ..... 'and so on'
End While
```

Comment: This is more on track, im getting the correct email now, but i would have expected the results to show ie, Job Number, Job ID. i get "6", its giving the number of rows affected.

Comment: I cannot see any code in your example that tries to read the field values, so I have excluded the SELECT <fields> parts in favor of a more simple way to check if record exists. Of course, if you need to read the fields then an update will be necessary.

Comment: Im probably looking at this from the wrong angle then, i assumed that by using SELECT like in SQL Manager that this is what would have been returned.

Comment: Iv used UPDATE in previous applications but that was to amend the DB, not Read results and display them in an Email which is what im having the issue with.

Comment: Wrong choice of word, update meaning I need to update my answer, not use UPDATE statement. Sorry

Comment: Using this method above which you have updated im getting "InvalidCaseException was unhandled when running, and how would these then be called in an email?

Comment: I am assuming that the first 3 fields were of integer data type, if this is not the case change to reader(0) etc.... updating

Comment: OK now im getting this through without errors, my next step is to take whats being returned and add it to an Email. However if i add jobID() or jobID(0) into the SENDEmail its asking to set up a sub.

Comment: Im a fool, Forgot to do, Dim jobID = reader(0)
            Dim jobNumber = reader(1)
            Dim appID = reader(2)
            s = s & jobID & ", " & jobNumber & ", " and then use S in the Email. All looks good now, many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are want to execute a query but are using **ExecuteNonQuery()**. Try using a [SqlDataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) like this:

```
Public Function SelectSqlSrvRows(dataSet As DataSet, connection As String, query As String) As DataSet
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connection)
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter()
    adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn)
    adapter.Fill(dataset)
    Return dataset
End Function
```